# Netbeans or Eclipse on macOS Sierra - Java problems

Tags: macos, java, eclipse

I want to install Eclipse or Netbeans on macOS Sierra. When I try to run Eclipse, I get an warning that Java 6 is needed. I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse to be sure.

[image: To open Eclipse you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime]

So I tried Netbeans:

[image: Netbeans - No JDK found]

While at the same time the System settings report that Java 8 is installed and up to date.

[image: macOS System settings for Java]

**How can I get either Eclipse or Netbeans working on macOS Sierra?**

Comment: Which version of eclipse and you should have the 64bit one and what java did you  install?

Comment: Java 8 version 121, see the screenshot. Eclipse Neon (eclipse-inst-mac64.tar.gz) so 64 bit - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R2a/eclipse-inst-mac64.tar.gz&mirror_id=1208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the full JDK version of Java 8 (`jdk-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg`) rather than just the JRE.

The JRE install does not include the support to run Java programs outside of a browser.